# Error connecting to remote mongodb inside the same network

Tags: mongodb, ssl, ssh, pymongo

I am trying to set up a connection to my host's mongodb from a client pc inside the same network. Here are the contents of my conf file on the host:

```
# where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: PATH_TO_DB
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  PATH_TO_LOG\mongod.log
  quiet: true

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, localhost, 192.168.X.XXX
```

where the X's are numbers specifying the private network ip of my host pc.

When trying to connect to the db from the client via python:

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.X.XXX:27017/')
```

and testing the connection, I get the following error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 192.168.X.XXX:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: 
<TopologyDescription id: 62f22029b65b0358c6e03ca4, topology_type: Single, servers: 
[<ServerDescription ('192.168.X.XXX', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
error=NetworkTimeout('192.168.X.XXX:27017: timed out')>]>
```

Apparently, the client cannot connect to the hosted mongo db in time.

I tried different combinations of the IPs listed in the bindip setting, including adding 0.0.0.0. Nothing prevents the error from occurring. There must be something I have done wrong.

Usually, I connect to the db via SSH port forwarding. On my client ubuntu machine, I start a terminal forwarding the host's 27017 port to the client's 8000 port:

```
ssh -N -L 8000:192.168.X.XXX:27017 user@192.168.X.XXX
```

On the client, once the tunnel is up, I connect like this:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:8000/')
```

This works fine. But, I am now trying to get rid of the SSH tunnel, as I would like to connect directly via SSL/TLS, instead. The reason is that the SSH tunnel might limit the data transfer speed via the network and SSL/TLS is supposed to be faster, somebody told me. I need to transfer large amounts of data regularly, thus, this speed is important to me. Therefore, I would like to replace the SSH solution by a direct connection to the mongodb inside the network.

Can you help me with this? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Best, JZ

Comment: Use `bindIP: 0.0.0.0` If that does not solve your problem, review the MongoDB logs for startup error messages.

Comment: It still doesnt work. Do I need to edit firewall settings on my windows db host?

Comment: For your comment that SSL/TLS is faster. TLS enables encryption, which is never faster. However, additional HTTP features are enabled over TLS, but that does not apply to MongoDB as it is not acting as a web server.

Comment: I was told: "I suspect TLS will be more efficient as there is 2 extra steps with SSH. With SSH your data is sent from the server to its local SSHd to get encrypted and then sent to the client SSHd to get decrypted before being sent to the client driver. These extra steps might have a big influence on performance with 276 million data points." But in the case described above, I test without TLS or SSH, and try do directly connect with bindip 0.0.0.0, and it doesn't work, though they're in the same wifi network... and I don't understand why.

Comment: I also read somewhere that I may need to delete the mong .sock file. But on windows, there is no .sock file, right? And on my ubuntu machine, I only have pymongo installed, not mongo db as an app, so there is no sock file as well, I guess?

Comment: Another update: I tried finding my host pc from the ubuntu machine with ```nmap 192.168.1.0/24```. Several devices appeared, but, strangely, not my Windows PC. I believe this might be the reason why I cannot connect. When trying to scan specifically my host: ```nmap 192.168.X.XXX```, I get: Host seems down. try -Pn option. When I add -Pn, I get a successful scan report for my host, with its name recognized, and the open ports listed, but the port 27017 doesn't occur in the list of open ports (it appears as filtered only). So it seems to be a port issue? (which is strange because I already open

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the windows firewall blocking the connection. After inspecting the network with nmap, I found port 27017 displayed as "filtered", though nmap recognized the service occupying this port as mongod. Following the firewall steps in the mongo db documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/configure-windows-netsh-firewall/), in particular entering

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open mongod port 27017" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=27017
```

in the cmd, the port was shown as open afterwards, and connecting to the db now works fine, as does TLS encrypted connection.